# How to Hide Specific Pages to Anonymous Users

Tags: users

I need to be able to block the user's URL to be seen by anonymous users. Specifically:

http://www.mysite.com/users/user_name and http://www.mysite.com/user (which are the same page but different URLs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first can be done by not giving the permission to view user profiles to anonymous users. The latter is not the same page as for anonymous users that's where they login. Blocking it would prevent anyone from logging in.

Comment: Wow, this was so simple. I should have thought of it before! Thanks.